# How to start a new intent from a thread?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I'm trying to launch a new intent from the onPostExecute function of a class that extends AsyncTask. This class is written in the same .java file with the main activity class, and is executed in that main activity class's onCreate function.

```
public class AnnouncementsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        new GetAnnouncements().execute();
        // ...
    }

private class GetAnnouncements extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> announcementsList = null;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    protected void onPostExecute(Void requestResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(requestResult);
        // ...
        announcementsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        announcementsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Intent openInBrowserIntent = new Intent(AnnouncementsActivity.class, Uri.parse(announcementsList.get(position).get("link")));
            }
        });
        // ...
    }
}
}
```

The error I get is:

error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(Class,Uri) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Class cannot be converted to String) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable (argument mismatch; Class cannot be converted to Context)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(announcementsList.get(position).get("link")));
    startActivity(i);
```